# How to add data in nested document in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to structure a collection such that "mainCollection" => "Client" => "Location" => { ...data } . Client and Location have Client name and Location as IDs . I wanted to add data in this collection , and used

```
const docRef = await addDoc(
        collection(db, "mainCollection", "Client","Location"),
        {
            ...data
        }
    );
console.log(docRef.id);
```

which generated an id , I want to do it in such a way that id remains Location name

Results I got - [image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

Comment: Can you show an example of the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49640098

Answer (score 1):

You can set data into location doc ID as following:

```
firestore.doc(`/mainCollection/${clientDocID}/${locationColId}/${locationDocID}`).set({
  ... your data
}, {
 merge: true // you can remove these brackets if you don't need merge
})
```

Or if you want dynamic IDs:

```
const docRef = firestore.collection(`/mainCollection/${clientDocID}/${locationColId}/`).add({
  ... your data
})

console.log('Added document with ID: ', docRef.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

use `setDoc` with the document id already included in the docRef. One thing to keep in mind that setDoc will override the doc if already exist. While, `addDoc` auto assigns the document id.

```
 const location="California";
 const docRef =doc(db, "mainCollection", "Client", "Location", location);
 await setDoc(docRef, { ...data});
 console.log(docRef.id);
```

Comment: @HarshSingh Please don't try to write everything in one line. Separate the code whenever it get's too complex. Make it easier to read/understand and debug.